# Bidding: How to figure out if responder has 4 carder or 5 carder major?

Tags: bridge, bidding

Playing SAYC, you open 1 Minor. Left passes and partner bids 1 Major. How do you figure out if partner has 4 carder major or 5 carder?

Obviously if left overcalls, then partner can use a negative double to indicate  he has a 4 carder or bid 1 Major to show a 5 carder. But otherwise, is there any convention to figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

In general no, there is no convention to convey this information because it is not (yet) important enough to warrant co-opting a call sequence. The subsequent auction will enable the partners to first determine if an 8-card fit exists, then whether either notrump is a suitable contract, or notrump is unsuitable but only 7-card fits are available.

Opener will show 4-card support eagerly (either by an immediate raise or a delayed jump raise) so that Responder will know there is an 8-card fit.

If forced by Responder to make a preference then Opener's minimum return to Responder's will be assumed to show only 2 card support. This will often be passed unless Responder has unrevealed strength to compensate for the lack of fit

If Opener returns freely to Responder's first suit then this *delayed* support shows three cards. At this point Responder holding 5 can indicate this by passing, inviting game, or jumping to game depending on his knowledge of the combined partnership assets. If Responder holds only 4 cards then a choice must be made to play in a Moysian fit of the major; in notrump; or in some other suit.

An essential point to note in these auctions is that the *beginner's rush to rebid a 5-card suit* is a terrible habit, and to be avoided whenever possible. Fast rebids of a suit should be reserved for showing 6-card holdings, so that partner can freely raise to show 2, revealing the 8-card fit.

AN exception to the above exists when Opener rebids 1 Notrump. Many partnerships will play some variation on [Check-Back Stayman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stayman_convention#Checkback_Stayman) or [New Minor Forcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_minor_forcing) to then explore major suit fits in more detail.

**Update** - as noted below in a comment:

by "fast rebid" is meant "at the next round of bidding." The tempo of the rebid itself, slow or fast, cannot legally (or ethically) be taken into account by partner!

Comment: +1. clarification in case OP is relatively new to bridge: by "fast rebid" you mean, "at the next round of bidding." of course the tempo, slow or fast, of the rebid itself, cannot legally be taken into account by partner!

Comment: @hunter: Thank you for the reminder. Your point is well made and important at all levels.